# Camera initialization failed for Windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

I  developed one Windows mobile 6.5 application.
In my application camera option is available , with this i need to capture so many images but after capturing the 5 images it throwing exception  like "**Initialization Failed** " .

Here my code snippet .

```
                CameraCaptureDialog  cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureDialog();
                cameraCapture.Resolution = new Size(240, 320);
                cameraCapture.Owner = null;
                string directoryString = @"\My Documents";

                if (Directory.Exists(directoryString))
                {

                    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";


                }
                else
                {
                    string activeDir = @"\My Documents\";
                    string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, "SurveyImages");
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);

                    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";

                }

                cameraCapture.StillQuality = CameraCaptureStillQuality.High;

                cameraCapture.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still;

                if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
                {


                 }
```

How can i resolved this one .

Comment: Any code? That is no general error and may depdend on your code.

Comment: please check now i have edited

Comment: And how do you start over to make more than one photo. Please provide more code so we can see the start, the photo taking, the stop and the next photo taking.

Comment: i wrote above code in Button event

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
CameraCaptureDialog  cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureDialog();
cameraCapture.Resolution = new Size(240, 320);
cameraCapture.Owner = null;
string directoryString = @"\My Documents";
if (Directory.Exists(directoryString))
{
    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";
}
else
{
    string activeDir = @"\My Documents\";
    string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, "SurveyImages");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";
}
cameraCapture.StillQuality = CameraCaptureStillQuality.High;
cameraCapture.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still;
if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
{
   ???
}
```

to

```
CameraCaptureDialog  cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureDialog();
cameraCapture.Resolution = new Size(240, 320);
cameraCapture.Owner = null;
string directoryString = @"\My Documents";
if (Directory.Exists(directoryString))
{
    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";
}
else
{
    string activeDir = @"\My Documents\";
    string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, "SurveyImages");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
    cameraCapture.InitialDirectory = @"\My Documents\SurveyImages";
}
cameraCapture.StillQuality = CameraCaptureStillQuality.High;
cameraCapture.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still;
if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
{
   ???
}
cameraCapture.Dispose();
cameraCapture=null;
```

If that does not work for you, provide more code. The change ensures the cameraCapture object is cleared completely before you try to create a new one.